# How to populate "between dates" given start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tells me the start and end "reserve date" for a piece of equipment. I want to create and populate a new table, filling in all "between dates" along with the start and end date for a particular item. The new table should include the following columns:

```
Item Name  conferencename  reserved dates
```

Comment: What is your question?  What does your query look like so far?

Comment: I haven't created a query for this so far. and my question is " date range between two dates from a table and updating a table with start, between and end dates"

Comment: That is not a question, that is a string of words put together somehwhat resembling a sentence.   You need to state the problem CLEARLY, demonstrate what you have done to help yourself, and then show us whats in your way so we can help you with specific problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be the only one who finds this question quite interesting (- just not perfectly explained).

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ebe27/1) that shows one way of doing this using a cursor to populate the dates. The part of the script I believe you were asking for is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE EquipmentLog 
    ([Item Name] varchar(255),
     conferencename varchar(255),
     [reserved dates] datetime);

DECLARE @Item_Name varchar(255),
        @conferencename varchar(255),
        @start_reserve_date datetime,
        @end_reserve_date datetime,
        @reserve_date datetime

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT * FROM EquipmentRegister

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @Item_Name, @conferencename, @start_reserve_date, @end_reserve_date

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
    SET @reserve_date = @start_reserve_date
    WHILE (@reserve_date <= @end_reserve_date)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO EquipmentLog
        SELECT @Item_Name, @conferencename, @reserve_date

        SELECT @reserve_date = DATEADD(day, 1, @reserve_date)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    INTO @Item_Name, @conferencename, @start_reserve_date, @end_reserve_date
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, I am not really a developer, I just write queries once in a while and maybe I did a bad job at explaining what I wanted. But, when I checked it out on fiddle, it did seem to do what I wanted. Thanks, I will try it out in my system.

Comment: Steve, would it be a good idea to use the cursor in a trigger?

Comment: You mean so it populates the log table with dates as rows are added to the register table? Yes that should work - but bear in mind you may need additional scripts for dealing with updates and deletes if they are possible.